# Oracle SQL -> nested group functions and weird behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting familiar with pl\sql and I have a question about certain task.

I want to find the job with the lowest average salary, this is the solution from the script:

```
SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING AVG(salary) = (SELECT MIN(AVG(salary))
                      FROM employees
                      GROUP BY job_id);
```

and the answer is job_id -> PU_CLERK, AVG(salary) -> 2700

My first question is why this code won't work:

```
SELECT job_id, MIN(AVG(salary))
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id
```

I get an "not a single-group group function" error.
By googeling the error, almost every solution is: *To resolve the error, you can either remove the group function or column expression from the SELECT clause or you can add a GROUP BY clause that includes the column expressions.*

Then why isn't this working? I have column expression in group by clause. Someone already posted about this but everyone just gave different solution. I would really appreciate if someone can actually explain.

With this query:

```
SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id
ORDER BY(salary)
```

I get a list of average salaries and PU_CLERK is the lowest with 2700, just like in the solution.
But, if a limit a number of rows displayed with ROWNUM, i get different solution. So, this query:

```
SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
GROUP BY job_id
ORDER BY(salary)
```

gives solution of SH_CLERK and 2600. Why is that?
I tried working with FETCH but that just didn't work.

Also, this query:

```
SELECT MIN(AVG(salary))
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id
```

gives solution of 2700, but it is missing a job_id so I can know which job position that actually is.

Thanks in advance to everyone for the answers and comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working as you are effectively doing:

```sql
SELECT job_id,
       MIN(avg_sal)
FROM   (
  SELECT job_id,
         AVG(salary) AS avg_sal
  FROM   employees
  GROUP BY job_id
)
```

And, while there is a `GROUP BY` clause on the inner sub-query there is not one on the outer query and the `job_id` column is not aggregated.

---

If you want to aggregate the outer query then:

```sql
SELECT MIN(job_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY avg_sal),
       MIN(avg_sal)
FROM   (
  SELECT job_id,
         AVG(salary) AS avg_sal
  FROM   employees
  GROUP BY job_id
)
```

or, without the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(MIN(job_id)) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY AVG(salary)) AS job_id,
       MIN(AVG(salary))
FROM   employees
GROUP BY job_id
```

In which, everything is aggregated twice.

---

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` and order by the `AVG(salary)`:

```sql
SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id
ORDER BY AVG(salary)
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

or you can use `ROWNUM` with a nested sub-query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY job_id
  ORDER BY AVG(salary)
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c13124ac0f9a7a1c149796acab5ce3cb)*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I understand now. FETCH and LIMIT didn't work for me because of older Oracle version

Answer (score 2):

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848):

> You can nest aggregate functions. For example, the following example calculates the average of the maximum salaries of all the departments in the sample schema hr:
>
> ```
> SELECT AVG(MAX(salary))
>  FROM employees
>  GROUP BY department_id;
>
> AVG(MAX(SALARY))
> ----------------
>      10926.3333
> ```
>
> This calculation evaluates the inner aggregate (MAX(salary)) **for each group** defined by the GROUP BY clause (department_id), and aggregates the results again.

Because there's no way to syntactically divide `GROUP BY` columns to inner aggregation and outer aggregation, an outer aggregation is performed with no `GROUP BY` columns. You cannot place any non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list in case of nested aggregation, because these columns are not available in the context of the outermost aggregation.

The question about `ROWNUM` should be a different question, but an answer is the order of evaluation: `WHERE` is evaluated before `GROUP BY`.